# http request from iOS

Tags: ios, json, ios6, httprequest, afnetworking

I am trying to send a request to

```
"http://www.geocodefarm.com/api/forward/json/f0e3d8f953e83ca08c1eb487c64f9b3ecc379d5c/530 W Main St Anoka MN 55303 US/"
which returns a JSON.
```

Pasting the address in my browser returns a JSON, I just don't know how to do it in iOS

I tried the following in AFNetworking, but the return was:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x14930080 {
NSUnderlyingError=0x14753ac0 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

code:

```
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:"http://www.geocodefarm.com/api/forward/json/f0e3d8f953e83ca08c1eb487c64f9b3ecc379d5c/530 W Main St Anoka MN 55303 US/"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                                 initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
                } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
                // code
            }];
[operation start];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem most likely relies on your URL. All URLs used in NSURLRequest should be escaped. Try to escape your URL before using it:

```
NSString* yourURLString = @"http://www.geocodefarm.com/api/forward/json/f0e3d8f953e83ca08c1eb487c64f9b3ecc379d5c/530 W Main St Anoka MN 55303 US/";
NSString* escapedUrlString =[yourURLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following code for request,

```
NSString *aStr=@"http://www.geocodefarm.com/api/forward/json/f0e3d8f953e83ca08c1eb487c64f9b3ecc379d5c/530 W Main St Anoka MN 55303 US/";
NSString* aStrFinal =[aStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *aUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:aStrFinal];
NSURLRequest *aREquest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:aREquest delegate:self];
```

And get response in following code,

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

NSMutableDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                        JSONObjectWithData:data //1

                        options:kNilOptions
                        error:nil];
  NSLog(@"json===%@",json);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Do like this,

First, create a string to store the string

```
NSString *strigURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.geocodefarm.com/api/forward/json/f0e3d8f953e83ca08c1eb487c64f9b3ecc379d5c/530 W Main St Anoka MN 55303 US/"];
```

Initialise an object for NSURL

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strigURL];
```

To request

```
NSMutableURLRequest * request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse * response;
```

the data received from response

```
NSData * responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Encoded data

```
 output=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response : %@",output);
```

Comment: Synchronous requests are bad. God kills a kitten every time you use one.

Comment: @Cyrille,please tell me wat will happen in this

Comment: ***The whole application will be completely frozen*** until the DNS name is resolved, the connection is opened, the request is sent to the server, the server processes the request, and your device receives the returned data. That might take quite a long time. Synchronous requests are NEVER the correct solution.

Comment: oh, so I should use asynchronous request

Comment: Always, ever. That should not even be a question.

Comment: @Cyrille, can U please suggest me some good link for asynchronous request